# Comparring Arrays with For Loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Alright so I have been working on this one for a bit. I'm comparing the values of two arrays using a For Loop. Every time the array known as cart hits a number that can be found in the products array, it displays the info of the products array, for each time it is hit. I think my code itself is fine ( though I could be wrong) but it's not displaying the values. So I think there's something wrong with my execution of said process there. The codes as follows

```
function Fill(){
var txt=""
var products = new Array();
products[0] = {name: "refrigerator" , price:88.99, img:"img/refrigerator.jpg"};
products[1] = {name: "microwave oven" , price: 76.99 , img:"img/microwave.jpg"};
products[2] = {name: "dishwasher" , price:276.67 , img:"img/dishwasher.jpg"};
var carts = new Array ();   
carts[0]= 2;
carts[1]= 0;
carts[2]= 1;
carts[3]= 1;
carts[4]= 0;
carts[5]= 1;
carts[6]= 2;
carts[7]= 2;

for(var i=0; i < carts.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < products.length; j++){
        if(carts[i] == j){
    txt +=products[j].name + ' ' + products[j].price +" <img src='"+ products[j].img + "'>"
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML += txt
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well if it doesn't work then it's obviously not "fine".

Comment: Not an answer, but: you can massively shorten your code by using array-literal syntax like `var carts = [2,0,1,1,0,1,2,2];`

Comment: I believe you're comparing a reference with if(carts[i] == products[j]).  Is this what you want to do?

Comment: "*Every time the array known as cart hits a number that can be found in the products array...*" -- the `products` array doesn't have numbers; it has objects. Perhaps you want to compare *keys* in the `product` array to *values* in the `carts` array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update answer with ES6:

```js
const products=[{name:"refrigerator",price:88.99,img:"img/refrigerator.jpg"},{name:"microwave oven",price:76.99,img:"img/microwave.jpg"},{name:"dishwasher",price:276.67,img:"img/dishwasher.jpg"}];
const carts=[2,0,1,1,0,1,2,2];

const productsInCart = [...new Set(carts)]
.reduce((a,c)=>{
  a.set(c,products[c])
  return a;
}, new Map());

const res = carts.map(c=>{
  const {name, price, img} = productsInCart.get(c)
  return `${name} ${price} <img src="${img}"/>`;
}).join("");

document.body.innerHTML = res;
```

---

You should be comparing `carts[i]` with `j` otherwise you won't find anything

```js
var txt = ""
var products = new Array();
products[0] = {
  name: "refrigerator",
  price: 88.99,
  img: "img/refrigerator.jpg"
};
products[1] = {
  name: "microwave oven",
  price: 76.99,
  img: "img/microwave.jpg"
};
products[2] = {
  name: "dishwasher",
  price: 276.67,
  img: "img/dishwasher.jpg"
};
var carts = new Array();
carts[0] = 2;
carts[1] = 0;
carts[2] = 1;
carts[3] = 1;
carts[4] = 0;
carts[5] = 1;
carts[6] = 2;
carts[7] = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < carts.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < products.length; j++) {
    if (carts[i] == j) {
      txt = products[j].name + ' ' + products[j].price + " <img src='" + products[j].img + "'>"
      document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML += txt
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Your `txt` variable should be modified with `=` and not `+=`

You should optimize your code. `document.getElementById("answer")` could be initiated globally for example.

Comment: You answer seems a bit off... In the JSFiddle, it spits out `dishwasher, dishwasher refrigerator, dishwasher refrigerator microwave, dishwasher refrigerator microwave dishwasher, etc.` IE it's prints the list items multiple times like so: `(1, 1 2, 1 2 3, 1 2 3 4, 1 2 3 4 5, 1 2 3 4 5 6, ...)`

Comment: If you take the `document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML += txt` out of the loop, it will be correct. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/axc896w6/1/

Answer (score 3):

"carts" is an array of numbers (as per your source code) while "products" is an array of objects. So your condition "carts[i] == products[j]" will never fire.

Answer (score 1):

What's the value of your appliance variable?
It'll cause the code to error out.

**To also steal Alex's answer:** "carts" is an array of numbers (as per your source code) while "products" is an array of objects. So your condition "carts[i] == products[j]" will never fire.

Perhaps this is better?..

```js
carts[7]= 2;

for(var i=0; i < carts.length; i++){
   
      
    txt +=products[carts[i]].name + ' ' + products[carts[i]].price +" <img src='"+ products[carts[i]].img + "'>"
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML += txt
             
        
    }
```

Upvoting Grimbode's answer as it's pretty close to mine, but cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need the second for loop. You're trying to compare a number with a product object by doing this and it will never work. OK, assuming that what you are trying to achieve is that if carts[0]=2 you want the info for products[2] then try something like:

```
for(i=0; i<carts.length; i++) {
    if(i<products.length) {
        currProd=products[carts[i]];
        //Process the currProd object as you will

    }    
}
```